# Why can't I feed or breed animals in Minecraft: Xbox 360 Edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have wheat in my hand even if they look directly at the animals they still won't follow me. Also, there is no button at the bottom that says feed. Why?

Answer (score 10):

Minecraft for Xbox 360 is based on an older version of Minecraft<sup>1</sup>, and because of this, breeding is not available in it.

<sup>Note 1: specifically, Beta 1.6 with some additional backported features. Breeding was introduced in Beta 1.9.</sup>

Comment: Oh, that stinks :( but thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Not to worry. As of now, they are working to get the Adventure Update and pistons added into the game. The XBox version has reached 1 million+ downloads, so it'll be no surprise if they put their full attention on that game.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft for the Xbox 360 (MCX360) is a ported version of a much older version of the game - 1.6. Because of this, we don't get many of the newer features like breeding sheep and enchanting.

Don't worry, though, they have announced they will be updating MCX360 to Beta 1.7.3, which means we can get Pistons! And I'm sure they will continue to update MCX360 to later versions of Minecraft when they can.

Comment: Here is a related announcement: [Minecraft Xbox 360 Patch 1.7.3 Release Date 'Within 10 Days'](http://www.nowgamer.com/news/1464385/minecraft_xbox_360_patch_173_release_date_within_10_days.html)